# If no arguments are provided in the function, how do I test to see if it is left blank?

Tags: php

```
<?php    
/* Copyright Date
--------------------------*/
function copyright_date($creation_year) {
    $current_year = date('Y');

    if ($creation_year == $current_year || $creation_year == '') {
        echo $current_year;
    } 
    else {
        echo $creation_year . '-' . $current_year;
    }           
}
?>
```

If someone forgets to add the argument (the year the website was created), e.g.

```
<?php copyright_date(); ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php copyright_date(2009); ?>
```

**how would I test to see if the argument was left blank?** In my if statement, that's what $creation_year == '' is for, but since the argument isn't a string, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `$creation_year` an optional argument with a default value of `NULL`.

```
function copyright_date($creation_year=NULL) {
```

Now inside the function just test if `$creation_year` is equal to `NULL`, which will happen when the function is called with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you MUST use [`func_num_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php). It's much more safer in practice.

```
function copyright_date($creation_year = NULL) {
    if(!func_num_args()) {
        // Nothing passed to the function
    }
}
```

why? Because if you set a default value, let's say `function copyright_date($creation_year = NULL)` you wouldn't know if NULL is passed. Also `isset()` returns `true` if you set a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) function

```
if ($creation_year == $current_year || !isset($creation_year)){
 //...
}
```

Comment: That is not a variable definition but an argument with default value.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have warnings turned on, leaving off function arguments generates warnings.  As long as we have armies of programmers willing to write warning/notice generating code due to laziness, it will continue to call into question PHP's suitability as a serious language.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs additional clarification on the answer:

You can try to set a function's parameters to NULL. This will set the value of the variable (in your case $creation_year) to an empty variable. The variable has been declared, but contains no value. When the function is called like so:

```
<?php copyright_date();  ?>
```

Your function will execute the code in the else block.

If the function is called the other way (with argument supplied), like so:

```
 <?php copyright_date($creation_year);  ?>
```

The argument supplied replaces the the NULL value, and the code in the If block is run.

Considering this, you also need to have this :

```
|| $creation_year == NULL
```

In your if condition. This will check if the value of $creation_year is empty.